# no documents in new elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, connector

We use couchbase elastic-search connector to index our search requirements

We have few indexes running fine and we are able to search for documents

Recently we created new index xm_index in elasticsearch

added new index information in default-connector.toml of couchbase-elasticsearch-connector

But we see no documents getting indexed into newly created index

Tried restarting couchbase-elasticsearch connector

```
[[elasticsearch.type]]
prefix = 'XM:'
index = 'xm_index'
```

Comment: Is it possible the documents with prefix 'XM:' are also matched by a type definition that appears earlier in the config? In that case, the first match wins and the documents will be written to the other index.